# m2eclipse eclipse europa 3.3.2 installation error

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse, eclipse-europa

I was trying to install m2eclipse in eclipse europa and encountered the following error. Kindly advise what needs to be done to install m2eclipse plugin in eclipse europa

```
Network connection problems encountered during search.
  Unable to access "http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/".
    Error parsing site stream. [White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.]
    White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
    Error parsing site stream. [White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.]
    White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
```

Comment: Why use europa? It's ancient!

Answer (score 4):

m2eclipse is compatible with 3.5.2 and 3.6.1 as per [this documentation](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html).  This could explain your error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are exactly following instructions [as mentioned here](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html) and still not functional tru older version. It might help: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/archives/m2e-0.10.2.20100623-1649/

Comment: I had tried the core site(http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e) and the archive site. Both give the same error.

Comment: well, better jump to latest version. It's free.

Answer (score 1):

Sonatype recommends installing m2eclipse on Eclipse 3.5 or Eclipse 3.6, and to make use of m2eclipse you will need to install the JDK. 
U can try with ..Eclipse 3.5 or Eclipse 3.6

Answer (score 1):

You might try below link - 
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/0.10.0.20100209-0800/

It worked for me with Eclipse 3.3 - Europa